# Solr Admin server - basic query request not returning results

Tags: solr, solrnet

I'm new to Solr and the Solrnet technology; I'm stumped with what seems to be something very basic; I haven't found any assistance on searching on the web.

I'm using Solr 8.1 and Solrnet 1.0.19

Using the Solr Admin console I'm able to query using the wildcard `(*:*)`.  However using a string that I know is in a document returns num found:0 (I have also been unsuccessful querying from the code).

Here's the code to index and delete my documents:

```
List<Course> eItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Course>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\PathTo\jsonFile\AllItems.json"));
try
  {
     var solr = SolrInstance.LocateSolrServer();
     solr.Delete(SolrQuery.All);
     solr.Commit();
     foreach (Item eItem in eItems)
     {
         solr.Add(eItem);
     }
     //commit to the solr engine
     solr.Commit();
```

I've added `<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>` to the default solrconfig.xml.

I'm also using the default schema.xml file, I've just added my own fields:

```
    <field name="idofitem" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" ></field>
    <field name="titleofitem" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" ></field>
    <field name="urlofitem" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="subjectofitem" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

  <uniqueKey>idofitem</uniqueKey>
```

I've been unable to get past this problem; please if anyone has any suggestions...I'm stumped.

Comment: You need to be more specific here: _using a string that I know is in a document returns num found:0_, how do you query that specific string and in which field to you expect Solr to retrieve it ?

Comment: Be aware that if you're not giving a field name when querying, the default search field is used. This is usually `_text_`, so if you're not indexing content into that field, either manually or through `copyField` instructions, you won't get any hits. Prefix your query with the field name (`titleofitem:word`), or use the edismax handler together with `qf`: `defType=edismax&q=word&qf=titleofitem subjectofitem`

Comment: Supplying a field name does work, thank you.  However I have a requirement that allows for the user to search on any word(s); just like using your favorite search engine.  Is there a configuration setting to search all fields or is this something that must be  programmed?